# How do I use angular2_material in angular2?

Tags: angular

I often see a reference to angular2_material (https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2_material) when reading up on angular2 changelog. I also saw this commit 
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/408618b8 showing usage of the new package: prefix.

I know Angular2 is still in alpha but does anyone have a working (there are many old out-of-date examples that aren't working anymore because so much has changed already) examples out there? I'm currently on alpha33

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/urish/angular2-material-build). Also, Check out [this demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QtOsjtDvUGuTYmDTmm6f?p=preview). See:

```
import {MdCheckbox} from 'angular2_material/material';
```

Comment: It does not work - i see no input field or label. Also it's based on an old alpha (23).